# How to create a new column for month and date according to the row number in R

Tags: r

Edited:
I am new to R language. I have a dataset which has 366 rows. I want to add a new column for month according to the row number which represents the day. How do I do it?

```
row   month
1     Jan
2     Jan
3     Jan
4     Jan
... 
32    Feb
...
70    March
...
366   December
```

This is the expected output I wish to have

Comment: Would you please show us reproducible data and your expected outcome? :) You can use `dput(your_data)` to share your data/subset of your data. For more info, run `?dput`. :) This way, you will get help much faster.

Comment: may you add the output `dput(<your_data>)` here so that it easier for other to understand what you started with? Also you mention the month & date but of what year? or just generic day/month? May you add some more information about the expected output? And what have you try so far?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. You're likely not to get a good response given the lack of example data and example code. Furthermore, it seems that your problem boils down to `rownames(data)` and then extraction information on the month and date. Depending on how those are formatted, you'll have to think about how to look for something like that on Google.

Answer (score 1):

if your rows number are `1:366` you could use `as.Date` and specifying the date of `origin`(because it is not possible to know the year only from the day of the year)
An example assuming you are interested in the date of 2021

```
as.Date(1:366, origin = "2021-01-01")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution in `dplyr` using the built-in constant `month.abb`. The method is as follows: first, we 'translate' the numbers in `1:366` to dates of format `yyyy-mm-dd`; then, using `str_extract` from package `stringr` as well as lookaround (`-` sign on the left, `-` sign on the right) we extract the month part of the dates into `m_numb` and convert them to numeric; finally, we subset the `month.abb` constant on `m_numb` to get the months as (abbreviated) words:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(n, origin = "2021-01-01"),
         m_numb = as.numeric(str_extract(date, "(?<=-)\\d{2}(?=-)")),
         m_word = month.abb[m_numb])
  n       date m_numb m_word
1     1 2021-01-02      1    Jan
2     2 2021-01-03      1    Jan
3     3 2021-01-04      1    Jan
4     4 2021-01-05      1    Jan
5     5 2021-01-06      1    Jan
6     6 2021-01-07      1    Jan
7     7 2021-01-08      1    Jan
8     8 2021-01-09      1    Jan
9     9 2021-01-10      1    Jan
10   10 2021-01-11      1    Jan
11   11 2021-01-12      1    Jan
12   12 2021-01-13      1    Jan
13   13 2021-01-14      1    Jan
14   14 2021-01-15      1    Jan
15   15 2021-01-16      1    Jan
16   16 2021-01-17      1    Jan
17   17 2021-01-18      1    Jan
18   18 2021-01-19      1    Jan
19   19 2021-01-20      1    Jan
20   20 2021-01-21      1    Jan
21   21 2021-01-22      1    Jan
22   22 2021-01-23      1    Jan
23   23 2021-01-24      1    Jan
24   24 2021-01-25      1    Jan
25   25 2021-01-26      1    Jan
26   26 2021-01-27      1    Jan
27   27 2021-01-28      1    Jan
28   28 2021-01-29      1    Jan
29   29 2021-01-30      1    Jan
30   30 2021-01-31      1    Jan
31   31 2021-02-01      2    Feb
32   32 2021-02-02      2    Feb
33   33 2021-02-03      2    Feb
34   34 2021-02-04      2    Feb
35   35 2021-02-05      2    Feb
36   36 2021-02-06      2    Feb
37   37 2021-02-07      2    Feb
38   38 2021-02-08      2    Feb
39   39 2021-02-09      2    Feb
40   40 2021-02-10      2    Feb
41   41 2021-02-11      2    Feb
42   42 2021-02-12      2    Feb
43   43 2021-02-13      2    Feb
44   44 2021-02-14      2    Feb
45   45 2021-02-15      2    Feb
46   46 2021-02-16      2    Feb
47   47 2021-02-17      2    Feb
48   48 2021-02-18      2    Feb
49   49 2021-02-19      2    Feb
50   50 2021-02-20      2    Feb
51   51 2021-02-21      2    Feb
52   52 2021-02-22      2    Feb
53   53 2021-02-23      2    Feb
54   54 2021-02-24      2    Feb
55   55 2021-02-25      2    Feb
56   56 2021-02-26      2    Feb
57   57 2021-02-27      2    Feb
58   58 2021-02-28      2    Feb
59   59 2021-03-01      3    Mar
60   60 2021-03-02      3    Mar
61   61 2021-03-03      3    Mar
62   62 2021-03-04      3    Mar
63   63 2021-03-05      3    Mar
64   64 2021-03-06      3    Mar
65   65 2021-03-07      3    Mar
66   66 2021-03-08      3    Mar
67   67 2021-03-09      3    Mar
68   68 2021-03-10      3    Mar
69   69 2021-03-11      3    Mar
70   70 2021-03-12      3    Mar
71   71 2021-03-13      3    Mar
72   72 2021-03-14      3    Mar
73   73 2021-03-15      3    Mar
74   74 2021-03-16      3    Mar
75   75 2021-03-17      3    Mar
76   76 2021-03-18      3    Mar
77   77 2021-03-19      3    Mar
78   78 2021-03-20      3    Mar
79   79 2021-03-21      3    Mar
80   80 2021-03-22      3    Mar
81   81 2021-03-23      3    Mar
82   82 2021-03-24      3    Mar
83   83 2021-03-25      3    Mar
84   84 2021-03-26      3    Mar
85   85 2021-03-27      3    Mar
86   86 2021-03-28      3    Mar
87   87 2021-03-29      3    Mar
88   88 2021-03-30      3    Mar
89   89 2021-03-31      3    Mar
90   90 2021-04-01      4    Apr
91   91 2021-04-02      4    Apr
92   92 2021-04-03      4    Apr
93   93 2021-04-04      4    Apr
94   94 2021-04-05      4    Apr
95   95 2021-04-06      4    Apr
96   96 2021-04-07      4    Apr
97   97 2021-04-08      4    Apr
98   98 2021-04-09      4    Apr
99   99 2021-04-10      4    Apr
100 100 2021-04-11      4    Apr
101 101 2021-04-12      4    Apr
102 102 2021-04-13      4    Apr
103 103 2021-04-14      4    Apr
104 104 2021-04-15      4    Apr
105 105 2021-04-16      4    Apr
106 106 2021-04-17      4    Apr
107 107 2021-04-18      4    Apr
108 108 2021-04-19      4    Apr
109 109 2021-04-20      4    Apr
110 110 2021-04-21      4    Apr
111 111 2021-04-22      4    Apr
112 112 2021-04-23      4    Apr
113 113 2021-04-24      4    Apr
114 114 2021-04-25      4    Apr
115 115 2021-04-26      4    Apr
116 116 2021-04-27      4    Apr
117 117 2021-04-28      4    Apr
118 118 2021-04-29      4    Apr
119 119 2021-04-30      4    Apr
120 120 2021-05-01      5    May
121 121 2021-05-02      5    May
122 122 2021-05-03      5    May
123 123 2021-05-04      5    May
124 124 2021-05-05      5    May
125 125 2021-05-06      5    May
126 126 2021-05-07      5    May
127 127 2021-05-08      5    May
128 128 2021-05-09      5    May
129 129 2021-05-10      5    May
130 130 2021-05-11      5    May
131 131 2021-05-12      5    May
132 132 2021-05-13      5    May
133 133 2021-05-14      5    May
134 134 2021-05-15      5    May
135 135 2021-05-16      5    May
136 136 2021-05-17      5    May
137 137 2021-05-18      5    May
138 138 2021-05-19      5    May
139 139 2021-05-20      5    May
140 140 2021-05-21      5    May
141 141 2021-05-22      5    May
142 142 2021-05-23      5    May
143 143 2021-05-24      5    May
144 144 2021-05-25      5    May
145 145 2021-05-26      5    May
146 146 2021-05-27      5    May
147 147 2021-05-28      5    May
148 148 2021-05-29      5    May
149 149 2021-05-30      5    May
150 150 2021-05-31      5    May
151 151 2021-06-01      6    Jun
152 152 2021-06-02      6    Jun
153 153 2021-06-03      6    Jun
154 154 2021-06-04      6    Jun
155 155 2021-06-05      6    Jun
156 156 2021-06-06      6    Jun
157 157 2021-06-07      6    Jun
158 158 2021-06-08      6    Jun
159 159 2021-06-09      6    Jun
160 160 2021-06-10      6    Jun
161 161 2021-06-11      6    Jun
162 162 2021-06-12      6    Jun
163 163 2021-06-13      6    Jun
164 164 2021-06-14      6    Jun
165 165 2021-06-15      6    Jun
166 166 2021-06-16      6    Jun
167 167 2021-06-17      6    Jun
168 168 2021-06-18      6    Jun
169 169 2021-06-19      6    Jun
170 170 2021-06-20      6    Jun
171 171 2021-06-21      6    Jun
172 172 2021-06-22      6    Jun
173 173 2021-06-23      6    Jun
174 174 2021-06-24      6    Jun
175 175 2021-06-25      6    Jun
176 176 2021-06-26      6    Jun
177 177 2021-06-27      6    Jun
178 178 2021-06-28      6    Jun
179 179 2021-06-29      6    Jun
180 180 2021-06-30      6    Jun
181 181 2021-07-01      7    Jul
182 182 2021-07-02      7    Jul
183 183 2021-07-03      7    Jul
184 184 2021-07-04      7    Jul
185 185 2021-07-05      7    Jul
186 186 2021-07-06      7    Jul
187 187 2021-07-07      7    Jul
188 188 2021-07-08      7    Jul
189 189 2021-07-09      7    Jul
190 190 2021-07-10      7    Jul
191 191 2021-07-11      7    Jul
192 192 2021-07-12      7    Jul
193 193 2021-07-13      7    Jul
194 194 2021-07-14      7    Jul
195 195 2021-07-15      7    Jul
196 196 2021-07-16      7    Jul
197 197 2021-07-17      7    Jul
198 198 2021-07-18      7    Jul
199 199 2021-07-19      7    Jul
200 200 2021-07-20      7    Jul
201 201 2021-07-21      7    Jul
202 202 2021-07-22      7    Jul
203 203 2021-07-23      7    Jul
204 204 2021-07-24      7    Jul
205 205 2021-07-25      7    Jul
206 206 2021-07-26      7    Jul
207 207 2021-07-27      7    Jul
208 208 2021-07-28      7    Jul
209 209 2021-07-29      7    Jul
210 210 2021-07-30      7    Jul
211 211 2021-07-31      7    Jul
212 212 2021-08-01      8    Aug
213 213 2021-08-02      8    Aug
214 214 2021-08-03      8    Aug
215 215 2021-08-04      8    Aug
216 216 2021-08-05      8    Aug
217 217 2021-08-06      8    Aug
218 218 2021-08-07      8    Aug
219 219 2021-08-08      8    Aug
220 220 2021-08-09      8    Aug
221 221 2021-08-10      8    Aug
222 222 2021-08-11      8    Aug
223 223 2021-08-12      8    Aug
224 224 2021-08-13      8    Aug
225 225 2021-08-14      8    Aug
226 226 2021-08-15      8    Aug
227 227 2021-08-16      8    Aug
228 228 2021-08-17      8    Aug
229 229 2021-08-18      8    Aug
230 230 2021-08-19      8    Aug
231 231 2021-08-20      8    Aug
232 232 2021-08-21      8    Aug
233 233 2021-08-22      8    Aug
234 234 2021-08-23      8    Aug
235 235 2021-08-24      8    Aug
236 236 2021-08-25      8    Aug
237 237 2021-08-26      8    Aug
238 238 2021-08-27      8    Aug
239 239 2021-08-28      8    Aug
240 240 2021-08-29      8    Aug
241 241 2021-08-30      8    Aug
242 242 2021-08-31      8    Aug
243 243 2021-09-01      9    Sep
244 244 2021-09-02      9    Sep
245 245 2021-09-03      9    Sep
246 246 2021-09-04      9    Sep
247 247 2021-09-05      9    Sep
248 248 2021-09-06      9    Sep
249 249 2021-09-07      9    Sep
250 250 2021-09-08      9    Sep
 [ reached 'max' / getOption("max.print") -- omitted 116 rows ]
```

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  n = 1:366
)
```

Answer (score 0):

From the sequence 1:366 create a date object of any leap year with origin as the last date of previous year so that 1 corresponds to 1st Jan of that year. Use `format` get month name from the date.

```
data <- tibble::tibble(row = 1:366, 
                       date = as.Date(row, origin = "2019-12-31"), 
                       month = format(date, '%b'))

head(data)

#    row date       month
#  <int> <date>     <chr>
#1     1 2020-01-01 Jan  
#2     2 2020-01-02 Jan  
#3     3 2020-01-03 Jan  
#4     4 2020-01-04 Jan  
#5     5 2020-01-05 Jan  
#6     6 2020-01-06 Jan  

tail(data)

#   row date       month
#  <int> <date>     <chr>
#1   361 2020-12-26 Dec  
#2   362 2020-12-27 Dec  
#3   363 2020-12-28 Dec  
#4   364 2020-12-29 Dec  
#5   365 2020-12-30 Dec  
#6   366 2020-12-31 Dec
```

Comment: Could use `'%B'` since OP wants full names

Comment: Well, OP has both full and abbreviated names in the output, they use `Jan`, `Feb` as well as `March` and `December` in the output so I am not sure what exactly they are looking for. But yes, in general `'%b'` for abbreviated names and `'%B'` for full names.